# Assistance needed with proxifier

Tags: proxy, tunnel

I have a PC which is protected with a firewall/proxy. The proxy allows me to surf all the sites I want, but blocks the internet for most of the applications that need internet access.  My questions are the following...

1)  Will proxifier portable do the job on its own to solve the application connection issue, or does it require additional software with it?  If yes, which and how to setup?

2)  Is proxifier detectable, in the sense from administrators?  If it is, is there any solution to it?

I am a bit of a newbie in this area so if possible please try to give me as much info as possible in your answer so that a newbie like me can follow :-)

Comment: You'll need to configure each application you want to use the proxy, to use it. If the application has insufficient support, you're kind of SoL. As for detectability, a sufficiently keen admin may be able to see the traffic. The traffic is still happening, though it may be encrypted, depending on your proxy.. So in the best case, a keen admin would at least know you're doing something, but wouldn't know for sure what.. Unless they're really adept at cracking encrypted stuff too..

Comment: I'm interested in one application in partiuclar so hopefully there will not be many configurations which need to be made.  If I understood you well I will therefore need to configure 'proxifier' to allow this particular application, correct?  No need for other software?  I didn't quite understand the, "insufficient support, you're kind of SoL" bit.  From what I can gather my application needs port 443 open.  Now as far as I know port 443 is used for https and I can browse secure sites, so I cannot understand how come this application's connection gets blocked.  Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I don't know what "proxifier" really is. When I proxy things, I have to configure a proxy service (usually on the same computer as the applications I'm using with the proxy), then I have to configure the applications to direct their traffic in to the proxy. The proxies that I use don't care what traffic they proxy, they'll just pass along whatever comes their way. But maybe proxifier is something different.

Comment: @Doc  I haven't used it but it seems quite apparent that the idea with Proxifier, is you don't have to configure individual apps. "Proxifier is a program that allows network applications that do not support working through proxy servers to operate through an HTTPS or SOCKS proxy or a chain of proxy servers."

Comment: Try it on your own home computer. Then at the other place, if you run it portable app, as a test, in practice they won't spot anything. But if you consistently do things through a proxy, then in theory they might view logs and see something fishy is going on, though it's possible that in practice, they won't do that 'cos so many people browsing, and on the internet, they won't see one off thing by one user or even logs on a per user basis.

Comment: If you can as a test, configure a web browser to use a proxy, then it probably means any app can use a proxy if not directly then through proxifier(assuming I read what proxifier does correctly). So you could do that little test prior to trying proxifier

Answer (score 1):

1. Proxifier portable alone will work. You can download free trial and test it.
2. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

1) Proxifier needs to route traffic someplace. If your organization has a SOCKS4 or SOCKS5 proxy or a HTTP "CONNECT" proxy available, you can configure proxifier to route traffic through that proxy without having to reconfigure each application.

You can use ssh to open an outbound proxy if you have ssh access. ie:

> ssh -D :1080 remote.example.com

will open a localhost:1080 SOCKS proxy supporting TCP protocols only and forward those requests through remote.example.com   You then setup a proxifier profile to use this proxy.

2) yes. Proxifier is detectable by administrators. Sophos and other commercial firewalls can be setup to block proxifier.

You can try Proxifier out for free for 31 days here:

https://www.proxifier.com/download/

Documentation here:

https://www.proxifier.com/docs/